# Unknown entity type: Namespace\Module\Model\Name requested

Tags: magento2

I am trying to understand this exception: `Unknown entity type: Namespace\Module\Model\Name requested`

I have a module and I am loading it like this in my controller:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Namespace\Module\Model\Name::class);
$model->load($id);
```

and in my resource model: `class Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name`, I have this:

```
/**
 * Load an object
 *
 * @param AbstractModel $object
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param string $field field to load by (defaults to model id)
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function load(AbstractModel $object, $value, $field = null)
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->load($object, $value);
    return $this;
}
```

Then in my `di.xml`, I have got this:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\RepositoryFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="entities" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">my_table</item>
                <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">my_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>


<type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\AttributePool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="myName" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="read" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler</item>
                    <item name="create" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SaveHandler</item>
                    <item name="update" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**Why is that throwing the exception?**

**How do I understand this `MetadataPool`?**

**UPDATE 1**

I have checked further and found that `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool::getMetadata($entityType)` is receiving `Namespace\Module\Model\Name` as argument. It supposed to receive `Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface`.

Doing `var_dump($this->metadata)` does shows there is `Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface` in the `$this->metadata` array.

What am I missing?

Comment: [this is helpful to you.](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1330)

Comment: Have checked `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool::getMetadata($entityType)`, but cannot find the culprit. Plez check updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so I have forgotten to implement `NameInterface` to my model `Name`.

Once added the interface implementation, right `$entityType` was passed and was loading successfully.

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;

class Name extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel implements \Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface
{
}
```

And, obviously `<preference for="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Name" />` in my `di.xml`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I am also facing the same issue i have followed step but not working because of in my `di.xml`  `<preference for="Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Data\Name" />` so what can i do for this scenario?

Comment: Have you implemented interface to your model class? `class Name extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel implements \Namespace\Module\Api\Data\NameInterface`

Answer (score 2):

```
 <!-- Register the Abstract Repositories -->
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\RepositoryFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="entities" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Namespace\Module\Api\NameRepositoryInterface" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Api\NameRepositoryInterface</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: This doesn't help.